# Regular Expressions - how to replace a character within quotes

Tags: regex

Hello regular expression experts,

There has never been a string manipulation problem I couldn't resolve with regular expressions until now, at least in an elegant manner using just one step. Here is the sample data I'm working with:

> 0,"section1","(7) Delivery of
>   'certificate' outside the United
>   States prohibited. Since both section
>   339 of the 1940 statute, 68/ and
>   section 341 of the present law are
>   explicit in their statement that the
>   certificate shall be furnished the
>   citizen, only if such individual is at
>   the time within the United States, it
>   is clear that the document could not
>   and cannot be delivered outside the
>   United States.",http://www.google.com/
>
> 1,"section2",,http://www.google.com/
>
> 2,"section3",",,",http://www.google.com/

This is a section of a much larger CSV file. With one elegant regular expression, I'd like to replace only all the commas that occur within the double quotes with an underscore character (_). It is important that the regular expression does NOT replace any commas outside the quotes because that would mess up the CSV data structure.

Thanks,
Tom

--

CLARIFICATION:

Sorry guys, I posted the question without fully clarifying my situation, so let me summarize below:

- Assume that quotes within quotes are already escaped (quotes within quotes in a CSV file saved by Excel are represented by `""` or `"""` etc., so they are easily replaced beforehand).
- I am working within JavaScript.

Using the sample text above, here is what it SHOULD look like after running the regular expression replacement (there should be a total of 5 replacements):

> 0,"section1","(7) Delivery of
>   'certificate' outside the United
>   States prohibited. Since both section
>   339 of the 1940 statute_ 68/ and
>   section 341 of the present law are
>   explicit in their statement that the
>   certificate shall be furnished the
>   citizen_ only if such individual is at
>   the time within the United States_ it
>   is clear that the document could not
>   and cannot be delivered outside the
>   United States.",http://www.google.com/
>
> 1,"section2",,http://www.google.com/
>
> 2,"section3","__",http://www.google.com/

Comment: how are you escaping quotes within quotes?

Comment: @Assaf, good question; please see my clarification above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll help you, but you have to promise to stop using the word "elegant".  It's been working too hard lately, and deserves a rest. :P

```
(?m),(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*")*[^"\r\n]*$)
```

This matches a comma if, between the comma and the end of the record, there's an odd number of quotation marks.  I'm assuming a standard CSV format, in which a record ends at the next line separator that isn't enclosed in quotes.  Line separators are legal inside quoted fields, as are quotes if they're escaped with another quote.

Depending on which regex flavor you're using, you may have to use `\r?$` instead of just `$`.  In .NET, for example, only the linefeed (`\n`) is considered a line separator.  But in Java, `$` matches before the `\r` in `\r\n`, but not between the `\r` and the `\n` (unless you set UNIX_LINES mode).

Comment: Alan Moore, you are a regular expression expert :-). Out of all of the solutions that I've received here (and elsewhere), your one super regular expression was able to do exactly what I described in my question, even before I posted my clarification. Bonus points, and YES your solution is "elegant" when compared to the solution I would've come up with (requiring multiple regexps and an array for temporary storage).

Comment: @Alan, I used your regular expression as-is except I left out ?: -- is there another use for this apart from memorizing the match?

Comment: @10basetom: In many regex flavors, if you use capturing groups in the split regex, whatever they capture gets added to the results along with the regular tokens.  But I confess I wasn't even thinking about that at the time.  I was just following the rule of thumb: never use a capturing group if a non-capturing group can do the job.  Each additional capturing group adds a little more to the resource overhead, both hardware and wetware (i.e., it becomes more difficult for the you the author to keep track of which group is capturing what).

Comment: @Alan Moore: Thanks for the input. I had the same thought as you ("Each additional capturing group adds a little more to the resource overhead") and decided to keep ?: -- even if any savings is trivial, it never hurts to add it.

Comment: Is there any way of getting this regex to work with the JavaScript replace function?

Comment: @Knix: `/,(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*")*[^"\r\n]*$/mg` should do it.  The only thing JavaScript would object to is the inline modifier, `(?m)`; I used `/m` instead.  And the "global" modifier, `/g`, tells it to replace all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: @Alan, I just had to throw in one more parens and it worked beautifully!  Thanks! `/,(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*")*[^"\r\n]*$)/mg`

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not particularly good at matching balanced text (i.e. starting and ending quotes).

A naïve approach would be to repeatedly apply something like this (until it no longer matched):

```
s/(^[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*?)"([^",]*),([^"]*)"/$1"$2_$3"/
```

But that wouldn't work with escaped quotes. The best (i.e. simplest, most readable, and most maintanable) solution is to **use a CSV file parser**, go through all the field values one by one (replacing commas with underscores as you go), then write it back out to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if you're not using Python, in which is the following code.
I didn't see any indication of which language you use. Anyway, I think the code is perfectly understandable.

```
import re

ch = '''0,"section1","(7) Delivery of 'certificate' outside the United States prohibited.
Since both section 339 of the 1940 statute, 68/ and section 341 of the present law are explicit
in their statement that the certificate shall be furnished the citizen, only if such individual
is at the time within the United States, it is clear that the document could not and cannot be
delivered outside the United States.",http://www.google.com/

1,"section2",,http://www.google.com/

2,"section3",",,",http://www.google.com/
'''

poto = re.compile('("[^"]+")')

def comma_replacement(match):
    return match.group().replace(',','_')

print poto.sub(comma_replacement , ch)
```

This method keeps the 2 adjacent commas in the line

1,"section2",,http://www.google.com/

unchanged. 
Is it the right thing you want ?