# Regular expression - replace \n within quotes

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a CSV file which needs all of the `\n` characters replacing with `<br>`, I found an answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476812/regular-expressions-how-to-replace-a-character-within-quotes) that I have tried to modify but it's matching all line returns.

```
(?m)\n(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"\n]*"[^"]*")*[^"\n]*$)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You mean you want to match a literal character string \n and not a real line break (which is what \n would normally match)?

Comment: Which language? ...and don't say RegEx ;-)

Comment: Do you *have* to use regex?

Comment: A simple string.replace("\n", "<br>") would work too.

Comment: Regular expressions are BAD for parsing grammars. If you are parsing a file that has quotes, escaped quotes, etc, you are going to have one nasty regular expression at the end that will be unmaintainable.  I suggest instead either using a package that is designed to parse CSV files properly (with all the possible quoting issues that can come up), then loop through the elements and do string.Replace("\n","<br>") and then save the CSV file using your package. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: @mbratch yes that's right :)

Comment: @SimonCatlin I'm using Sublime 2's regular expression find and replace search input. It's an text editor but seems to work with regular expressions pretty well. Plus you can can see what is being selected as you create the reg exp.

Comment: @NullUserException no not at all but thought this might be a good way of doing it, of course it being reg exp, it's turned out to be a challenge!

Comment: @MarkLakata thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Did you try just changing the `\n` to `\\n` in the regex?

Comment: @mbratch yes, that doesn't match anything when I do that unfortunately. Any other ideas?