# replace all commas within a quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

is there any way to capture and replace all the commas within a string contained within quotation marks and not any commas outside of it. I'd like to change them to pipes, however this:

`/("(.*?)?,(.*?)")/gm`

is only getting the first instance:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uxuceTu/1/edit)

Comment: Can you give us some "before and after" strings so that we are sure of the situation?  For example, can there be multiple double quote pairs in the string and, if so, should it replace the commas in all of them?

Comment: @talemyn yes, that's true. There could be multiple quoted strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If callbacks are okay, you can go for something like this:

```
var str = '"test, test2, & test3",1324,,,,http://www.asdf.com';

var result = str.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function (match) {
    return match.replace(/,/g, '|');
});

console.log(result);
//"test| test2| & test3",1324,,,,http://www.asdf.com
```

Comment: Is is possible to use `exec()` to acheive this instead of two `replace()`. MDN says I can use it to run a pattern against a string several times, but I cannot understand how.

Comment: @thomas `exec` won't replace anything, so you'd need to do this anyway. If you're searching for *one* regex, [this read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476812/regular-expressions-how-to-replace-a-character-within-quotes?rq=1) might help you out, but knowing how bad JS is at regular expressions compared to PCRE (it lacks a lot of lookbehind and lookahead) then it possibly wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is very convoluted compared to regular expression version, however, I wanted to do this if just for the sake of experiment:

```
var PEG = require("pegjs");

var parser = PEG.buildParser(
    ["start = seq",
     "delimited = d:[^,\"]* { return d; }",
     "quoted = q:[^\"]* { return q; }",
     "quote = q:[\"] { return q; }",
     "comma = c:[,] { return ''; }",
     "dseq = delimited comma dseq / delimited",
     "string = quote dseq quote",
     "seq = quoted string seq / quoted quote? quoted?"].join("\n")
);

function flatten(array) {
    return (array instanceof Array) ?
        [].concat.apply([], array.map(flatten)) :
        array;
}

flatten(parser.parse('foo "bar,bur,ber" baz "bbbr" "blerh')).join("");
// 'foo "barburber" baz "bbbr" "blerh'
```

I don't advise you to do this in this particular case, but maybe it will create some interest :)

PS. `pegjs` can be found here: (I'm not an author and have no affiliation, I simply like PEG) http://pegjs.majda.cz/documentation